# Xcode 7 UI Debugging Recording. No buildable for testable

Tags: xcode, cocoa, testing, record, xcode-ui-testing

Xcode prompts "No buildable for testable" when the record button is clicked.

In my Xcode project, targetting for iOS, there is an Objective-C testing target and a Swift testing target, both for UI Testing. As guided by the Apple UITestingGuidelines, I moved the insertion point to the testExample function and clicked the record button. Immediately after the button is released, there is a pop-up alert with message "No buildable for testable". I've already tried restart the project several times but it did not work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image: Had to change this]

- Here is a picture for the setting that resolved the issue for me.
- It was set to "None" I chose my target application instead.
- I had to expand the little sidebar by clicking the button to the right of the selected "wiserIos M" column.

Comment: The picture is very helpful for those who may not know where to look. If you app is already selected, try selecting "None" and then select you app as was suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 21):

My solution was go to project setting. Set target application to None and then back to original app. And it works

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem.
My solution was to delete all testing targets and simply recreate them. Afterwards ensure your testcase has the correct target membership. Now it should work.

Comment: Thank you. I deleted both the Tests & UITests folders in the project navigator as well as the Test & UITest targets referenced in the show project and targets list.